# subprocess.communicate(input_string) still tries to read input from stdin

Tags: python, unix, subprocess

I am trying to utilize a python subprocess to run an executable binary with input.

My executable takes as input a JSON object and does stuff with it. If you run the executable on its own it will block waiting for input from stdin.

The following command runs just fine on the terminal:

```
echo '{"values":{"value_1":"1122","value_2":"abcd"}}' | ../path/to/bin/executable-script -option1=x -topic my_kafka_topic
```

But I need to generate the input JSONs in my python script. so I am right now trying this:

```
import sys
import subprocess

if __name__ == '__main__':

    input_string = '{\"values\":{\"value_1\":\"1122\",\"value_2\":\"abcd\"}}'
    input_bytes = [elem.encode("hex") for elem in input_string]

    bashCommand = '../path/to/bin/executable-script -option1=x -topic my_kafka_topic'
    process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print 'program blocks on next line'
    data, error = process.communicate(input=input_bytes)
    print 'data is {}'.format(data)
```

unfortunately my program will not run inside the python script, it will just block waiting for me to type in input. if I type in input it works fine.

but I don't want it to block. I want it to run just like in the command line. how do I do this?

Comment: Aside: Don't use `bashCommand.split()`. Specify it as an array to start with. Otherwise, you'll have bugs whenever you want to specify a filename or other input with literal spaces.

Comment: And the name `bashCommand` is misleading if you're running it without any shell at all -- it implies that shell syntax like `2>err.log` will work if added to the line, but this implication is utterly false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing an argument to `process.communicate()` is correct, but you also need to pass `stdin=subprocess.PIPE`. Thus:

```
command = ['../path/to/bin/executable-script', '-option1=x', '-topic', 'my_kafka_topic']
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
#                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
process.communicate(input_data)
```